# Routing traffic through custom tap device en-route to internet on linux

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, iptables

I have a VM that is using a tap device (`tap2`) and my goal is to filter all the traffic in/out of `tap2` using a custom program written by me that runs in userspace.

The topology I came up with routes traffic from `tap2` to `tap1` where my process is listening to frames and any that are allowed to go onwards to their destination are passed through to `tap0` which is connected to `enp0s25` using a traditional NAT setup.

```
                                  ┌─────────────────────────┐                                  
                                  │                         │                                  
                                  │                         │                                  
                                  │                         │                                  
                                  │Userspace filter process │                                  
                              ┌──▶│                         │───┐                              
                              │   │                         │   │                              
                              │   │                         │   │                              
┌────────┐        ┌────────┐  │   │                         │   │   ┌────────┐       ┌────────┐
│        │        │  tap1  │  │   └─────────────────────────┘   │   │  tap0  │       │        │
│  tap2  │───────▶│        │──┘                                 └──▶│        │──────▶│  enp0s25  │
│        │        │        │                                        │        │       │        │
└────────┘        └────────┘                                        └────────┘       └────────┘
     ▲                                                                                         
     │                                                                                         
     │                                                                                         
     │                                                                                         
┌────────┐                                                                                     
│        │                                                                                     
│   VM   │                                                                                     
│        │                                                                                     
└────────┘
```

I am stuck basically at the first portion of this topology. I have a simple python program that connects to `tap1` and prints out any frames it sees: https://gist.github.com/shriphani/f98c212e0f4eb8d63ce3059a28509441

Then, I bring up the appropriate devices:

`tap1`:

```
sudo ip tuntap add tap1 mode tap user shriphani
sudo ip addr add 172.19.0.1/24 dev tap1
sudo ip link set tap1 up
```

`tap2`:

```
sudo ip tuntap add tap2 mode tap user shriphani
sudo ip addr add 172.20.0.1/24 dev tap2
sudo ip link set tap2 up
```

Following this, I added a route from tap2 to tap1:

`sudo ip route add 172.20.0.0/24 via dev tap1`

which results in this error message:

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

and this is the routing table:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s25 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.16 metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.19.0.0/24 dev tap1 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
172.20.0.0/24 dev tap2 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.16
192.168.1.1 dev enp0s25 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.16 metric 100
```

Which is doubly weird since I don't see that exact route I asked for in the routing table.

Anyway, I then added these `iptables` commands:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tap2 -o tap1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --in-interface tap2 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface tap1 -j MASQUERADE
```

and my understanding is, I allow traffic from `tap2` -> `tap1`, route all `tap2` to `tap1` (to that particular IP addr - not sure if this is right), and then all outgoing traffic from `tap1` appears to be coming from `tap1` (so far I have no outgoing traffic yet).

When I run my python script attached to `tap1`, and `wget google.com` from the VM, I see absolutely nothing printed. Pinging the tap IP range from the host causes the script to respond (i.e. I do `ping 172.19.0.2` on the host and the script prints something).

So I have 2 questions about this setup:

1. Is this topology sensible or are there simpler ways of achieving my goals
2. If this is a good topology, what exact set of rules do I need to force all traffic from the VM (`tap2`) to first appear at `tap1` following which I can send it out.

Thank you very much. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The routes confuse me a lot. What exactly is the point of `172.20.0.0/24 via dev tap1`? That subnet doesn't belong to tap1, does it? What's the IP address that the actual VM has?

Comment: 172.20.0.0/24 is the address range of tap2 (where the VM is on). I am using firecracker to manage my VM and that takes up the whole tap device for itself. The VM itself is on 172.20.0.2

Comment: Exactly, so it makes no sense to route that /24 via tap1 in your case.

Comment: Ok, what rules do you think I should have if I want all tap2 traffic to go through tap1?